# Default collation of temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, collation, temp-tables

How can I check what the collation of a temporary table is?

I want to do this because I want to check what happens if I have database with a specific collation, different from the SQL Server instance and create a temporary table.

Let's say we have this scenario:

SQL Server 2008 - `Latin1_General_CS_AS`

Test Database - `Estonian_CS_AS`

Then create table `#Test` without specifying the collation. Which will be the collation of the table?

I think `Estonian_CS_AS`, but in the test I am doing is said `Latin1_General_CS_AS`. That's why I need to find a SQL statement to check this.

Note: from what I have read, I think that the collation of a temporary objects is defined by the `tempdb` collation. But if this is true, what defines its kind?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`tempdb` is recreated when the server start and gets the collation from the `model` database.

Temp tables you create without specifying the collation will have the collation of `tempdb`. When creating temp table you can use [`database_default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) as collation to get the same collation as the current database.